# Should I write out the JSON structure of an api call as an interface in typescript to interact with values inside response?

Tags: json, typescript

So i'm just starting out with typescript and something that I can't find much info on is how to deal with types for api call responses.

Lets say, I make a GET request to an api and it returns a JSON object for example:

```
{
 name: "john",
 age: 12
}
```

in my code, if i wanted to interact with `response.name` would i have to create an interface like below to use `response.name` without having a red linter under it?

```
interface Response {
 name: string,
 age: number 
}
```

or is there a easier way to do it as some api calls would return JSON > 10 lines long and copying out the whole structure for every type of call seems very troublesome. Another thought I had was to create the interface but only have values I would use instead of the whole structure, but i'm not too sure so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `Response` as a "common" type, that supports all types of API json response.

```
interface IResponse {
  [key: string]: any
}
```

Now, you can type `response.name` without the "red line", also `response.not_exist_property` is valid.

My recommendation is to define all types for all API response type:

```
interface GetUserResponse {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}
```

for `GET /users/:id` (example)

You can use [this tool](https://jvilk.com/MakeTypes/) to convert a json response to Typescript type.